# Compute the term frequency–inverse document frequency with NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I'm using NLTK to compute the tf_idf of words. But most of them have a score of 0.

```
def compute_tf_idf(corpus,source_text):
    texts = []
    for text in corpus:
        if text['text'] != None:
            try:
                language = detect_lang(text['text'])
            except Exception as e:
                language = None
            # French analysing
            if language == "french":
                french_analyser = AnalyseFrenchText(text['text'])
                french_analyser.analysetext()
                tokenized_text = french_analyser.get_tokenized_text()
            if tokenized_text != None:
                texts.append(tokenized_text)
    textCorpus = TextCollection(texts)
    for word in textCorpus[:100]:
        print(word) # print correctly words
    try:
        language = detect_lang(source_text)
    except Exception as e:
        language = None
    # French analysing
    if language == "french":
        french_analyser = AnalyseFrenchText(source_text)
        french_analyser.analysetext()
        tokenized_source_text = french_analyser.get_tokenized_text()
    for word in tokenized_source_text:
        print(word)
        print("idf :" + str(textCorpus.idf(word)))
        print("tf : " + str(textCorpus.tf(word,tokenized_source_text)))
        print("tf_idf :" + str(textCorpus.tf_idf(word,tokenized_source_text)))
    return
```

Result:

```
Commande
idf :0.0
tf : 0.0024875621890547263
tf_idf :0.0
```

I checked NLTK source for the computation of idf:

```
 """ The number of texts in the corpus divided by the
    number of texts that the term appears in.
    If a term does not appear in the corpus, 0.0 is returned. """
```

Do I use the tf_idf of NLTK wrong ?
Thank you

Comment: Could you post the full code or a link to your code? Currently, given the code snippet you've posted, it's unclear where the problem might be. Also, if possible post your corpus sample somewhere otherwise it's unclear too.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `nltk`'s implementation of the TF-IDF calculation, so I'm not sure what you mean "what should I change for an optimal tf_idf score". What you can change is not to guess; find out what the contents of your `TextCollection` look like, whether it thinks "succursales" is in it, etc.

You can check if a word is in a `TextCollection` (`True` or `False`) like this:

```
print("succursales" in mytexts)
```

To get a feel for what's actually in `mytexts`, you could iterate like this:

```
for word in mytexts[:100]:
    print(word)
```

My guess is that you'll see single letters. The constructor to `TextCollection` expects a list of tokens (words), and it doesn't look like you've done that.

Also you need to pass a list of tokens to `tf()`, and it should be **one of the documents in the corpus**, not the entire corpus. But you're passing some kind of corpus object. In other words, read the docs so you understand what these functions are for, and how to call them.

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking some time to help me. I updated my question to reflect your input. Could you verify if i'm doing it right ? Thank you

Comment: 1. Fix your indentation. 2. Show where `source_text` comes from and what it looks like (no, not the original text itself but the contents of the variable.) 3. You really have `for word in tokenized_source_text:` and you get data for **one** word in the output?

Comment: source_text is a string which contains a full text.
The ouput is way longer, all the words from source_text are computed.